# WillPopScope not working when using several navigators

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying in my app to add local scope per tab. To achieve this I have added several navigator keys that are passed in to the views that need to have their own navigation. These views are visible in tabs, that is the main navigator that my app uses.

The keys look like this:

```
final _navKeys = {
  Tabs.tab1: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  Tabs.tab2: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
  Tabs.tab3: GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
};
```

These keys are then passed to a TabNavigator that exists inside the tab that needs its own stack:

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
```

To make the decision if we should pop the stack when navigating back I have added a Navigator and a WillPopScope in the TabNavigator. However the WillPopScope in the TabNavigator is never hit, it always hits the top level WillPopScope for the tab navigation. What am I doing wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:m3u_nullsafe/m3u_nullsafe.dart';

import '../main.dart';
import 'empty_type.dart';

class TabNavigator extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabNavigator(
      {super.key, required this.navigatorKey, required this.type});
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey;
  final Map<String, List<M3uGenericEntry>> type;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (navigatorKey.currentState != null) {
          navigatorKey.currentState!.maybePop();
          return false;
        }

        return true;
      },
      child: Navigator(
          key: navigatorKey,
          onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => Column(children: [
                      if (type.isEmpty) const EmptyType(type: 'type'),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView(
                            children: type.entries.map((e) {
                          var w = ListTile(
                              title: Text(e.key),
                              onTap: () => {
                                    navigatorKey.currentState!.push(
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (_) =>
                                            CategoryListView(entries: e.value),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  });
                          return w;
                        }).toList()),
                      ),
                    ]));
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didnt get this to work. So I decided to rewrite the navigation in my app with [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). All views now work.